# Cannot get HC-12 to function with Arduino Pro Micro clone

Tags: wireless, arduino-pro-micro

[first time usage]

I'm checking this config out with a simple sketch derived from one @ https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/understanding-and-implementing-the-hc-12-wireless-transceiver-module/.

The sketch acknowledges a command from the Serial Monitor and responds accordingly along with an "OK".  I have used this sketch countless times before with numerous HC-12 and UNO, and this particular HC-12 functions properly when connected to such.

For the Pro Micro, the command is echoed back instead, which, in my experience, indicates that the HC-12 is not receiving/responding.

The Pro Micro test config is very basic: Pro Micro, HC-12, USB connection, 5 direct jumper connections for vcc, gnd, pins 4-6. Vcc output reads 4.2 volts.

I specify:

```
const byte HC12RxdPin = 4; // "RXD" Pin on HC12
const byte HC12TxdPin = 5; // "TXD" Pin on HC12
const byte HC12SetPin = 6; // "SET" Pin on HC12

SoftwareSerial HC12(HC12TxdPin, HC12RxdPin)
```

I have also tested with an IN4007 in the power connect for the HC-12, but results are the same.

I've swapped HC-12s, and checked out the requisite pins by using another sketch that toggles an led on each.
The Arduino IDE is 1.8.2, and I am specifying a Leonardo board.  This is the suggestion I found whilst researching.

I have seen a few projects using the HC-12 with the Pro Micro and other small boards, but noticed no special considerations for such.

Have you any suggestions or solutions [even better]?

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/arduino-pro-micro-get-data-out-of-tx-pin?rq=1

Comment: mico Thanks to the reference cited, I think I finally comprehend the situation.  Reading was easy, comprehension more difficult.

Based upon the reference, I removed the HC-12 specifications, then specified Serial1 for the reads, writes and available check.

I then changed connections, such that the HC-12 RXD pin connects to the Pro Micro TXD pin, and the HC-12 TXD pin connects to the Pro Micro RXD pin.

This works for my the sketch I was using as well as other test cases of mine.

Comment: Have you seen the Q&A on providing adequate power?  The HC-12 needs more than 100 mA to work, into the Vin, for all types of Arduino..  It will not work at all if the power is only coming from a USB port.  Have you tried this?  https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33668/how-can-i-provide-enough-power-on-an-uno-to-use-the-hc-12-wireless-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to problem is as follows:
 For the Arduino Pro Micro [as for the Leonardo], Serial1 must be used instead of a SoftwareSerial specification, e.g.,

```
SoftwareSerial HC12(HC12TxdPin, HC12RxdPin).
```

Code is to be modified by changing HC12.available() to Serial1.available().  The same holds true for the reads and writes.
Pins are to be wired such that the HC-12 RXD pin connects to the Pro Micro TXD pin, and the HC-12 TXD pin connects to the Pro Micro RXD pin. 
My thanks to @mico for providing the reference that explains it all.